# Current state of art approaches in generating features based on other available features and items

Tags: text-generation, state-of-the-art

I am about to do a project that is about generating texts for missing entries that are related to some object (using information about other available entries related to the same object and corresponding entries in other similar objects) and my question is where I can find good litterature about state of art approaches that manage problems like these (or at least other problems that are related to this one my project will concern which I could consider while doing this project).

Thank you in advance!